# Add the ability of changing background color of a theme

Tags: theme-development

I am trying to teach myself developing wp themes and I am wondering how I can add the ability of changing the **header background color** at customize section of the theme.

Details: I have started with _underscore and I notice that there is no color setting for background of the header section. There is a "Color" section that allows me to change the text color of the header but there is no option for the background color or the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start off by studying about Theme_Customization_API [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API).

For your specific problem follow this [link](http://buildwpyourself.com/building-theme-color-options-customizer/).